# Verisign file error when signing a xap file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sign, xap, verisign

We bought an authenticode certificate to sign a xap file on Verisign.com and after the registration completed, we received the certificate.

I installed it on my computer and I can now select it in my Visual Studio solution. The problem is, even after getting no error after the build process, when deploying it, I cannot have any certification client side.

I followed the following article, without success, what could I be missing ?

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2011/04/27/silverlight-5-beta-rough-notes-trusted-apps-in-the-browser.aspx

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my problem.

When launching a Silverlight XAP file in a "In-browser" mode, each client HAS to manually deploy those two things :

**1) A key in the registry to allow the In-Browser mode :**

For 32 bits System :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight]
"AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\Components]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Silverlight\Components\Debugging]
```

For 64 bits System :

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight]
"AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\Components]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\Components\Debugging]
```

**2) Install my certificate into the "TrustedPublisher" store using the utility called "MMC".**

Unlike Out-of-browser and install modes, when using the In-browser mode, each client has to perform those steps ! I've initially thought that those steps were automatic and that the client just had to confirm for their installation... That's not the case...

Hope it helps.